# Why does a hypersonic missile need to cruise Earth at low altitude before hitting its mark?

Tags: technology, military-defense, weapon-mass-destruction, nuclear-war

Imagine a certain nation tested a hypersonic nuclear-capable missile and it was designed to make a few trips around the Earth at low altitude before striking the surface. Don't they need to worry about the prolonged period of time the missile needs to survive the temperature of aerodynamic friction from air colliding with the missile? It increases exponentially with speed and at hypersonic velocities (5-10 times the speed of sound) the temperature around the missile should melt most metals known to science.

My question is why risk a nuke since so far no one is capable of intercepting it anyway? Why not just plot a direct route and let it scram at low altitude until it crashed into the target zone if efficiency is all that matters?

Comment: Most of the presumptions here are untrue.  A stagnation point in fluid dynamics is the point where the fluid goes on either side of the moving body, and has nothing to do with the temperature.  Tantalum, tungsten, rhenium and other metals have melting points well above the temperatures generated by friction in hypersonic flight, and can be used in alloys, or ceramics can be employed as they were in Project Pluto or reentry vehicles.

Comment: @jdunlop the major problem is heat propagation through the heatshield. A lovely refractory coating stops your missile/re-entry vehicles burning up, but it will still conduct heat in and it will still be ablated away... its a delaying technique, and the OP's suggestion probably requires it to delay for too long. Also, the stagnation point is where the temperature is gonna be highest. See also: [stagnation temperature](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/BGH/stagtmp.html).

Comment: @jdunlop also, I believe project pluto and its modern equivalents are supersonic, but are not hypersonic. I'm not 100% certain on that though, so if anyone knows otherwise I'd happily be corrected.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate... Related broader question, with applicable answers though, was put yesterday: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/227075/how-does-orbital-warfare-work

Comment: The actual problem here is that you need a world which has hypersonic nuclear missiles which orbit earth at low altitudes several times before hitting their target? And we need to justify these world-touring missiles? Someone tell me how this isn't the actual story, because a story which needs this device in its world escapes me.

Comment: @VogonPoet: to justify the space laser program...?

Comment: The fuel requirements alone make this prohibitive.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. No need to orbit in the atmosphere. The ballistic trajectory goes outside the atmosphere, where there is no air, no friction.
2. No way a rocket could fly a few trips around the planet in the atmosphere anyway. Energy-wise, it will run out of fuel going against such drag.
3. Even if re-entry is to be endured for a long time, we have materials for that. Ceramics and heavy metals can withstand it. The temperature of plasma near the ship will be larger than the melting point, but the surface will not be as hot.
4. It is actually easy to intercept low orbit stuff. The energy required to intercept a low orbit is about 10 times less than the energy needed to go into that orbit. Even much less technically advanced nations can intercept an orbit, even if they can't go there. Lots of our anti-air rockets designed to hit a plane can intercept a low orbit, actually, with very few changes. The chances for a successful interception are much lower than for a plane unless changes are significant, but still, numbers can help, and no bleeding edge tech is needed.

The reason why orbital weapons are so deadly is that they can stay in orbit for years. Not just 3 turns, but thousands of turns. Then it is more of a weapon storage, that can be utilized at any point in time. If there is no war yet, and a nation puts nukes in orbit, then another nation needs to either intercept them right now, before they activate, or just accept that they can't do it later. Once a nuke decided to drop from orbit onto a target - it cannot be intercepted, not even by most modern tech. Nukes can only be intercepted in the speed-up phase, or if they are staying in orbit.

If you know that a nuke is going to hit in 20 minutes, it is somewhat better than not knowing when it is going to hit at all. A nuke from orbit can wait for 3 years, and then drop in just 3 minutes. Normal nukes with their 20 minute delivery time give at least some time to run to a bunker, or launch a response. But orbital nukes with their delivery time of just a few minutes give no such chances. You either live in a bunker, or just accept that you will not have a chance to get to it.

Comment: Do you have a source for "_drop in just 3 minutes_"? Prompt re-entry requires big engines, and big heatshields. If you're referring to the Soviet-era [fractional-orbit bombardment system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Orbital_Bombardment_System), be aware that the FOBS had an orbit low enough that it _couldn't_ be sustained for years, as atmospheric drag would sweep it out of orbit in fairly short order.

Comment: @StarfishPrime current rockets that go to orbit do so in 3 minutes, thats their active phase. I assumed about the same time to go down. Using engine to actively slow down. They likely will not need as much fuel, as a lot of slowing down can be made by reentry friction. There is no such system, so I cant give you a link. From basic calculations, 2km/s delta v will allow to drop the orbit by 360 km in 3 minutes. And once in atmosphere, 50km or so,can dive. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55371-vectorized-orbital-decay-routine-for-space-objects-between-180-and-500-km-altitude

Comment: @SurprisedSeagull Dropping the orbit is something different than dropping out of orbit. Any reasonably efficient burn can only change the altitude of the opposite side of the orbit. You then have to wait for half an orbital period to get to that part of the orbit to change your actual altitude. Indeed if you look at current rockets, they don't go into orbit in 3 minutes, but they burn for 3-5 minutes, then coast for ~20 minutes to get to the orbital altitude, then burn again to get to orbital velocity. The same time is needed in reverse. You can do it faster but only using much more fuel.

Comment: @mlk https://mars.nasa.gov/images/launch_sequence_diagram-full.jpg some example. 4 min 47 sec for 5.6 km/s. Opposite side of earth would require 40 minutes, and spend 100 m/s delta V, which is even longer than ICBM delivery for most targets. Why would military care about optimal deorbiting, if it makes this worse than land based ICBM? Why would military leave only 100 m/s delta V if 2km/s delta V is still quite possible? it is expensive. But it is the only way to make it better than land based ICBM. Time for delivery is critical for such a system. They will not care about optimal deorbiting.

Comment: @SurprisedSeagull You are looking at the wrong burn. The initial burn of a space launch is mostly to get the velocity from 0 to something hypersonic, you don't even need to reverse that for a weapon on the way back down. The point is that a stable orbit is only reached at MECO2 after 40 minutes. So if you start from orbit, you need to start there and work backwards. And military may care about somewhat optimal deorbiting, since the rocket equation means they get several times as many missiles that way for the same weight they initially launch to orbit.

Comment: @mlk 2 km/s delta v budget will make 3 times less wareheads https://www.spaceacademy.net.au/flight/spfl/rockeq.gif  So yes, it is costly. I know that orbital speed is 9km/s or so, and I offer to only use 2km/s, and the remaining 7km/s will stay, as diving nuke doesnt care about it. I do not offer to stop all 9km/s. Now, if you are a general, your options are: 3 (ok, may be 5min) orbital nuke, 40 min orbital nuke but 3 times as many (your case), and land based icbm with 30 minutes. Why would they ever chose your option? You either choose cheap, land based, or expensive and quick orbital nuke.

Comment: Note also that if you're putting things into sufficiently energetic orbits with the engines necessary to get back quickly then you don't actually need the expense of nuclear warheads.  See:  Kinetic Bombardment

Comment: @Perkins kinetic energy of orbital bombardment is x10 of tnt per weight. Nuclear warhead energy is x100 000 of tnt per weight. So no, not quite. Unless you orbit a much heavier body than Earth.

Comment: @SurprisedSeagull But unless you're a kill-crazy psychopath you don't generally actually *need* to level whole cities with a single strike and the kinetic impactors require far less maintenance, which is important for something that's going to be out of reach for possibly a long time.  You can also up the energy by using higher orbits, so depends on whether rocket fuel or plutonium is cheaper for you.

Comment: @Perkins putting stuff in orbit makes the cost of plutonium and rocket fuel almost the same. Whatever the orbit, you are getting at most escape velocity, that gives just x2 energy than low orbit, not worth the added time and cost to get there most likely. There is practical sense to use nukes over kinetic. Most targets consist of collection of objects, like vehicle parking, or targets are big, like a factory. Another point is precision. Error is about 100m currently. Kinetic projectile radius of destruction is a few meters, less for armored targets... So, no,it is still not useful for anything

Comment: @SurprisedSeagull  The calculations on proposed kinetic systems estimate a final yield around 11 tons of TNT.  About like a WWII era Grand Slam, only with much greater ground penetration depth. Or a fragmentation design would hit about like a modern MOAB. Smashing a whole parking lot of planes would be quite doable. A nuke of similar mass could level an entire city, sure, but (on top of that being a horrendous thing to do) nukes require too much maintenance to leave them floating in orbit for decades waiting to strike anywhere within minutes.

Comment: @Perkins thats 1 ton of matter. While lightest nuke is just 50kg. so, x20 complexity. Pu239 half life is 24k years, U235 half life is 0.7 billion years. They both are quite durable to stay in orbit for years. If something is to fail, thats the engine and fuel tanks and batteries. Another point is that this 1 ton rod you are offering will not just explode, it will carry its momentum deep into the ground. Very few of the exploding force will actually damage planes nearby. It sure will make a deep hole, but the same hole will protect the planes nearby. Sure, planes will get their paint chipped...

Comment: @SurprisedSeagull Plutonium cores are good for about 90 years, but the conventional explosives to trigger it require a high degree of precision which is lost after no more than 10. After that you just have a "dirty" bomb. The computer and maneuvering systems of even our older space probes are expected to get 30-40 years and they see heavy use. A bombardment satellite could theoretically last considerably longer. The rod could be made to fragment prior to impact to spread the blast over an area. This is being developed for rail gun projectiles, which are kinetic impactors of similar velocity.

Comment: @Perkins swan device requires precision, and that rots quickly, sure. But dumb linear type nuke requiers much simpler type of explosives, and thats what is used in small nukes. fragmenting rod is a really good idea though, i didnt think of that. With proper fragment size and some specific targets it can cover comparable area with damage as a nuke would. Interesting. But hey, all the explosive requirement is then the same. Only difference is that now you have just one type of target it can damage - depending on the fragmentarion size, while nuke is universal. Be it plane parking or a bunker.

Comment: @SurprisedSeagull  Linear type would have a longer shelf-life, but are also much less efficient and far dirtier.  Of the 63kg warhead in "little boy" it's estimated that only about 1kg actually underwent fission.  But it would be a workable option if you don't mind poisoning the whole planet with fallout. The explosives to fragment a rod don't have to be detonated simultaneously from multiple points within less than a microsecond of each other. It's that precision timing that makes clean, efficient spherical cores require regular maintenance.

Comment: @Perkins last time I checked military people were the least caring about the nature of all people - they use uranium tank projectiles after all. And about low efficiency of small nukes - it is still >1000 times more energy per mass than kinetic bombardment. Im not saying I would choose it. But I am saying people who make these decisions will care about things I mention more than about nature. Or efficiency. And about explosives - linear nuke explosives complexity is the same as fragmenting rod. Same explosive, same precision, same engine, just smaller. So time to stay in orbit is the same.

Comment: On the contrary, the terminal phase is the easiest one to intercept an orbital weapon. The whole point of FOBS was to attack from the direction there was no defense built, not to counter defense by going orbital. What's hard is short warning, but when one country launches an orbital nuclear platform, the others have years to build observatories dedicated to tracking this one platform specifically.

Comment: @Agent_L terminal phase, especially in atmosphere, is the hardest to intercept because of speed, maneurving, plasma that covers everything, no time to speed up something to even intercept it, random motion at re-entry, short distance. Try to name some condition when it is harder to intercept something else? Or try to name a method to intercept a nuke diving from orbit? Assuming non-optimal deorbiting. Everything i've read so far goes against of what you are saying

Comment: @SurprisedSeagull https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_missile_flight_phases#Terminal "Interceptions during the terminal phase are among the simplest, both technically and in terms of tracking." Note that LEO velocity and typical ballistic missile reentry are similar - 7km/s

Comment: @Agent_L To be clear, you use a point about missiles that are powered only during the speed up and then fly by inertia, to what I offer, where a missile is powered almost till the impact? Low angle, passive reentry against diving in, that provides even more control? You consider FOBS an issue even with 30 minute warning, just a few minites less than an ICBM would provide warning, but 3-5 minutes orbital nuke seems less dangerous for you? Im trying to understand how did you come to your conclusion

Comment: @SurprisedSeagull 1) No, deorbiting is not powered almost till the impact. 2) Orbital warhead enters at potentially lower angle than a ballistic one. To dive in you'd have to dead stop putting in -7km/s and then accelerate another 7km/s vertically. Those are both infeasible because of the fuel and impossible to do quick. 3) There is little control over deorbiting. 4) I nowhere said that FOBS is an issue. 5) more like 30 min than than 3. 6) I understand your error: focusing on how close to you orbiting object is so you completely miss how much harmful speed in the wrong direction it has.

Comment: There is a reason we've never built an orbital weapons platform - it's inferior to ballistic in all aspects.

Comment: @Agent_L 1) what I offer is powered in majlrity of deorbiting time. 2) ballistic fly up to 2000km, and 15 min from max height. What I offer is 450km orbit, and 3-5 min. Depends on engine and fuel, but could be better. There is no need -7km\s. -2km\s vertically will bring time till entering an atmosphere to a few minutes. Also no need to separate retrigrade and 'to planet' burn, can do 1 'diagonal' burn with less fuel cost. 3) it all depends on how much time the engine is on. In my case engine is on during deorbiting, so there is control.

Comment: @Agent_L 5) how did come to 30 min? 6) I actually calculated orbit, (400km), delta v (2km/s) to deorbit in a few minutes. did you?

Answer (score 9):

## Loitering

First, a hypersonic-capable missile need not remain at hypersonic speeds for its entire flight.  Many missiles differentiate thrust between cruising and final approach, saving sprint speeds for the last leg.

Further, if the missile uses a [nuclear ramjet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Pluto) as opposed to conventional rocketry, it could have a tremendous amount of endurance (neglecting all the reasons that's a *bad* idea), so in a major war situation, these missiles could be launched and set into holding patterns, circling the planet (or the target country) until commanded to go into their attack patterns.

Because they're so fast, the enemy has no way of intercepting them, so they provide a credible, and threatening, second-strike capability.  But the time in loiter mode means that they can also be *aborted* without hitting their targets.

Comment: So replacement for missile submarines?

Comment: Wear is extreme. We are talking minutes, hours at best. Even if reactor could work for months, wear from plasma will erode everything. We can shoot it down, firing to a place where the rocket will be, from the nose, as opposite to a more usual tail chase mode, both modes can be used, nose mode is less efficient, but not impossible. They are significantly slower than actual ballistic missile, because at orbital speed erosion will be even more extreme. And main point: it is not actually loitering. Destruction of a shockwave of this machine is more destructive than a nuke it carries. Seriously.

Answer (score 4):

**Sending a strong message**

Of course there is no need for the missile to circle around Earth before striking its target. Furthermore, as other answers and the question itself had mentioned, cruising at low altitude present enormous technical challenges which no nation had been able to solve so far.

Then why the attacker should take such a long time before the strike? The answer is to let the opponent know about its intentions. Traditional ballistic missile, or traditional cruise missile (or "traditional" hypersonic missile, for that matter) cannot be called off. It can not change its initial target either. The only option for the attacker is to self-destroy the missile mid flight if the attack needs to be aborted - and this option is often not available.

Thus, when the traditional missiles had left their silos, the world is already past the point of no return. Even if world leaders suddenly come to their senses and want to fix everything, it is hardly possible to do so.

Here comes a world cruising hypersonic missile. This missile is more akin to traditional nuclear bomber which can be called off - only much, much harder to intercept. After the launch, opponents would quickly know that there is an impending strike - but there is nothing that they can do except to negotiate with the attacker.

This answer assumes that cruising hypersonic missile is able to communicate with its flight control center.

P.S. I realized that my answer is essentially a variation of @jdunlop's answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Why not just plot a direct route and let it scram at low altitude until it crashed into the target zone if efficiency is all that matters?

1. That's how you get intercepted mid-flight.
2. Define efficiency. If a 500,000 dollars missile can demoralize the enemy with one shot when 50,000 dollar ones can't with 100 shots, which one do you prefer?

---

In the ongoing invasion of Ukraine, Russia is using their new Khinzal hypersonic missiles. They are not relevantly faster than other missiles that NATO, China and India have available - but they are extremely maneuverable (when compared to regular missiles, they still turn like any other rocket). In other words, they are not ballistic. They make random turns while in flight to evade anti-missile barrages. Some variants do go up to the higher atmosphere and possibly beyond.

The Khinzal spends most of its time flying at Mach 4, but can accelerate to Mach 10 at sprints. For comparison, India had the Shaurya which goes to Mach 7.5 in low altitudes, but is ballistic, since 2011 at least. [The US might soon have a hypersonic missile capable of reaching Mach 20](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AGM-183_ARRW). And China has anti-satellite missiles, which necessitate hypersonic flight and high maneuverability. So while this is all literally rocket science...

> Don't they need to worry about the prolonged period of time the missile needs to survive the temperature of aerodynamic friction from air colliding with the missile? It increases exponentially with speed and at hypersonic velocities (5-10 times the speed of sound) the temperature around the missile should melt most metals known to science.

... That same rocket science has already solved those problems time and again.

Comment: "they are extremely maneuverable" - Not in the usual sense. A Mach 10 missile, roughly 3 km/sec, maneuvering at 10 g's, will have a turn radius of about 100 km.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast In terms of banjaxing an intercept firing solution they're pretty damned maneuverable :P

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast maneuverability in terms of evasion is not just about how big of a turn you can pull, but how quickly you can move your cross section out of your expected path.  If you try to intercept a missile, and it moves over 1 meter in the last moment before you can correct your own course, it does not matter if that last moment included 10 meters for forward movement or 1000.

Comment: @Nosajimiki - Think of it in terns of lateral rate vs range. Let's say a target is approaching at closing rate of 1 km/sec, and when 1 km away begins a 10g turn, At intercept (after 1 second), it will have deviated 50 meters from its original path. With a closing rate of 10 km/sec, the deviation at impact will be .5 meters. This will be much easier to hit assuming a proximity fuse is used.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast You are measuring distance when you need to be measuring reaction time.  Whether your example missile is moving 1km/sec or 10km/sec, it can deviate by 50 meters/sec.  If you need to get within .5m to intercept, that means your interceptor has to be able to see and respond to a course correction within 1/100th of a second of impact to hit the target.  The big difference is that at .01 sec to impact, the slow missile will be 10m away whereas the fast missile will be 100m away making "seeing" that last centisecond maneuver harder because it is farther away.

Comment: Dodging a fast moving missile is easier because of its larger turn radius, but intercepting a fast moving missile is harder.  Khinzal missiles are Air-to-Surface missiles meaning you don't have a lot of opportunity to dodge them.

Answer (score 1):

### Mass panic puts time pressure on negotiations

Q: *"My question is why risk a nuke since so far no one is capable of intercepting it anyway? Why not just plot a direct route and let it scram at low altitude until it crashed into the target zone if efficiency is all that matters?"*

For *some reason*, the agressor decided to let the missile fly multiple rounds in the atmosphere.. at Mach-5, that will take about 6-7 hours for a round trip, depending on latitude of the flight path. It could be up there, for a day or two. I'll skip the feasibility analysis and technical frame challenges "it's a waste to do this", other answers have covered that. This is an attempt to improve on Alexander's answer. Why would this weapon be the perfect way, to put pressure?

**Extremely low orbit will not allow secrecy to prevent panic**

Say 200-500 feet altitude, modern guided missiles can do that. All the time, this frightening nuclear missile will fly over your populated areas, multiple times, visible to everyone in the target areas. It will be in all the newspapers. And feel like Russian roulette (what's in a name)

**Uncertainty: no tactical or strategical response, it could even be fake**

The defending army would get intimidated - air defense will do 3-4 attempts to intercept the thing.. and no attempt will succeed. That would undermine army moral. Especially at high command levels.. your country is a super power, you have many places around the world this missile could be intercepted, but it does not succeed. To deploy this missile is  a new strategy that's not in the books, there is no response either. The nuclear war head mounted on the missile could even be *bluff*, nobody knows for sure.

**Time pressure on negotiations**

Suppose you have to negotiate with the aggressor. His missile flying around for a day now, during the negotiations. The aggressor has the means to challenge you with a turn-key acute threat. This nuke can (and should) be cancelled at any moment, the aggressor needs to do that. If it does not happen, you can't prevent the damage and the aggressor has not even indicated a target. This would put enormous pressure on negotiations to give in, and meet demands quickly. You'll *beg them* to crash this hell machine into the Pacific ocean.

Comment: The problem with causing panic is that panic responses are unpredictable and often unreasoned.  The response could be 'hit them while we can' first strike.  This also assumes that the guided missile actually cannot be intercepted; the response does not prove whether it can be -- look up "Coventry" in WW II; a city which was allowed to be destroyed rather than showing the Germans that their secret communications were being intercepted and read, which traded a city against winning the war.  And then there's the rain of cruise missiles or bunker busters on the dictator's last known location...

Comment: One huge mistake in war is to assume that you know what will happen.  Well, it's probably safe to say "things you won't like will occur."